# Как в Android Studio отключить авто import?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Как в Android Studio отключить авто import у статических переменных?

```
class TestA{
   public static int asd=0;
}
```

---

```
class TestB{
  int asd=5;
  asd=2;
}
```

Как видно из примера, в классе TestB я записал переменную asd. В итоге, поменялось число 2 у класса TestA, потому что  Android Studio автоимпортировал класс TestA.

Если бы я хотел переписать статическую переменную asd класса TestA, я бы написал TestA.asd=2;

Кстати, это появилось в Android Studio 2.2.3, поэтому просьба - кто знает, как отключить это? Заранее говорю, мне отключить полностью авто импортирование не нужно, только для статических.

В Классе TestB автоматически создается import

`import static com.ruandroid.appone.TestA.asd;`

Comment: @pavlofff, Как правило AS и автор данной темы дурацкими быть не могут, с этим я согласен с вами.
По поводу. не понятности, а что для вас есть понятность?. Если вы хотите понять то можете прочитать 2 -3 раза и понять. Если же не понимаете, значит вы просто не хотите понимать. К тому же у вас должна быть такая же проблема чтобы понять, какой помощи я хочу от людей на данном сайте

Comment: Нашел ответ тут. Кому интерестно
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35005604/how-to-disable-automatic-java-static-imports

Comment: @pavlofff, Где кнопка оформить как мой ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для управления автоматическим импортом есть чекбоксы в меню <kbd>File</kbd> | <kbd>Settings</kbd> | <kbd>Editor</kbd> | <kbd>General</kbd> | <kbd>Auto Import</kbd>. На данный момент только один, но в ближайшем EAP-релизе будут отдельные флажки для импорта классов и методов/полей.

В IDEA 2016.2.1 и позже это настраивается флажком <kbd>Show import suggestions for static methods and field</kbd>

Источник: [How to disable automatic Java static imports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35005604/how-to-disable-automatic-java-static-imports)